# Spring (Java) - register vs list

Tags: java, spring

I have the following:

```
List<Color> acceptableColors;
```

Using Spring, would it be best to instantiate this list this way:

```
<bean>
    <list>
    <value ref="orange" />
    <value ref="yellow" />
    ....
    </list>
</bean>
```

Or, is there a way to do a register scheme, where we use Spring to perform the following Java code:

```
ColorRegister.register(orange)
ColorRegister.register(yellow)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spring [registers Color property editor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/validation.html#beans-beans-conversion) by default, so you can do the following:

```
<util:list id="acceptableColors">
  <value>255.127.0</value>
  <value>255.255.0</value>
</util:list>
```

The above would create a `List<Color>` instance. If you'd rather reference the colors by name you can [write your own property editor](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/validation.html#beans-beans-conversion-customeditor-registration)

Answer (score 1):

Without creating your own custom schema elements for Spring (which is possible and [documented](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/extensible-xml.html)), this is probably the best you can do, using the [`util`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.6/reference/xsd-config.html#xsd-config-body-schemas-util) schema/namespace:

```
<util:list id="acceptableColors">
    <ref bean="orange"/>
    <ref bean="yellow"/>
</util:list>
```